# how to push notification message count on app icon badge in samsung devices

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

I have create firebase push notification in my app. Push notification completely show in android device  but push notification message not count on app icon badge. 
In MI device Push notification message count on app icon badge. whats problem why samsung device is not count message on badge?

Comment: some devices supports badge count. some doesn't.. which device you are testing on?

Comment: samsung galaxy j2

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no way in Android as badge count are not part of platform.Some devices hardware supports as some devices are doesnt support badge count.There is no standard way for this .